# How to detect handlebars-created non-initialized modal closal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating, upon the press of a button, a modal window that comes from an handlebars template. At the document's load, the modal window is NOT initialized so you can't tie an event to it such as :

```
$(".modal").attr("someAttr").change(function(){});
```

Here is the code of the modal window and the hidden button that can be called to show the window once it's initialized.

```
    <script id="informationModalTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="modal fade informationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{Title}}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <textarea id="informationTextContainer" name="informationTextContainer">{{Content}}</textarea>
                            <a onclick="" class="button button-rounded button-reveal button-medium button-green tright"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i><span>OK</span></a>
                            <a onclick="" class="button button-rounded button-reveal button-medium button-red tright"><i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i><span>Cancel</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
```

Can someone please tell me how to detect when such a window gets closed?